# How to fix fatal git clone erorr?

Tags: git

I've used git clone in the past, but now I'm getting this weird error. I've seen other SO posts on this. I've tried:

1. Changing permissions in the folder. (Thus, the demonstration that I can make/remove a directory).
2. Running cmd/git bash as an admin.

These didn't work. Any ideas?

---

For some reason, the image is too big. I'll just paste what was displayed in git bash below:

```
plcla@PaulsXPS MINGW64 ~
$ cd OneDrive/Documents/All\ \ Documents/Programming/Mastering-the-Coding-Interview/

plcla@PaulsXPS MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/All  Documents/Programming/Mastering-the-Coding-Interview
$ mkdir hi

plcla@PaulsXPS MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/All  Documents/Programming/Mastering-the-Coding-Interview
$ dir
hi

plcla@PaulsXPS MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/All  Documents/Programming/Mastering-the-Coding-Interview
$ git clone https://github.com/plclauss/Master-the-Coding-Interview-DS-Algos..git
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'Master-the-Coding-Interview-DS-Algos.': Invalid argument

plcla@PaulsXPS MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/All  Documents/Programming/Mastering-the-Coding-Interview
$
```

Comment: Looks like a typo? `https://github.com/plclauss/Master-the-Coding-Interview-DS-Algos..git` has two periods at the end (`..git` instead of `.git`)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. The problem is that the repo's name is "Master-the-Coding-Interview-DS-Algos.", so when you add the ".git" extension, you get the two periods. I would've thought GitHub would've thrown an error when naming the repo, but it didn't. I can try it with that change.

Comment: This isn't a *Git* issue, it's a Windows (and/or OneDrive) issue. Git lets you name a repository `this...that...&the:other` but Windows rejects the colon forever. GitHub servers run Linux, not Windows. You can work around this part by naming the repository something else locally, e.g., `git clone <url> mcidsa` or some such. By the way, don't store repositories in cloud-synced folders either.

Comment: @torek Thanks. What's the reasoning behind your last remark?

Comment: Experience shows that when people do that, the syncer breaks their repositories, sooner or later.

Comment: @torek Understood. Does that still apply if I have all syncing turned off? I'm not even logged into my OneDrive via my laptop.

Comment: That *might* be safe, if the underlying file system implementation provides POSIX semantics (but most of these cloud-synced ones don't seem to do that).